# Document element null in template due to helper condition

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code is expected to show a progress bar animation when a button is clicked. The problem is that the progress element is null when the animation code tries to use it.

How can it be fixed? thx

```
Template.registerHelper('session', (value) => {
  return Session.get(value);
})

Template.footer.events({
'click button[data-action=carSearch]': function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clickInfo();
}
});


'clickInfo': function () {
   Session.set('inProgress', true); // makes the element visiable
   progressBarStart(); // start the animation
}

    'progressBarStart': function () {
      let bar = document.getElementById('bar'); //<-- bar is always null

      if (bar.value < 70) { 
        setTimeout(lib.progressBarStart(), 1000); controls the speed
        bar.value += 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
<template name="nameSearch">
  <div id="nameSearch">
    <p id="result" data-id={{_id}}>
      {{{display.result}}} <br>
      {{#if (session 'inProgress')}}
        <progress id="bar" value="0" max="70"></progress>
      {{/if}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the render a time to re-render after calling `Session.set('inProgress', true);`, 50ms will be enough.

Next, you should declare `clickInfo` and `progressBarStart` correctly, not like you have them now.

```
function clickInfo() {
  Session.set('inProgress', true);
  Meteor.setTimeout(progressBarStart, 50);
}

function progressBarStart() {
  ...
}
```

I'd also recommend to use dedicated helper to obtain `inProgress` status:

```
Template.footer.helpers({
  isInProgress: function() {
    return Session.equal('inProgress', true);
  }
});
```

And use it in your template:

```
{{#if isInProgress}
...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: you should avoid using session. Use reactive-vars.

Comment: There are no any reasons to NOT use session. Honestly, we don't know author requirements, perhaps he wants to use this variable in another templates, thus he is using session.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use Session variables for such a small reason. Meteor JS has given a facility to use Reactive Variables at template level manipulations.

You should give the render a time to re-render after calling `Template.instance().inProgress.set(true);`.

I'd also recommend to use dedicated helper to obtain `inProgress` status:

```
Template.footer.onCreated(function(){
  this.inProgress = new ReactiveVar(false);
});


Template.footer.helpers({
  isInProgress: function() {
    return Template.instance().inProgress.get();
  }
});
```

And use it in your template:

```
{{#if isInProgress}
...
{{/if}}
```